# How to serialize OData with data-annotation in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, dataverse

I was able to retrieve OData REST from Web API and working now on serializing the json data below:

Json data:

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://....crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.2/$metadata#msdyn_flow_approvalrequests(statuscode,msdyn_flow_approvalrequestid,statecode,msdyn_flow_approvalrequest_approval(statecode))",
  "@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.totalrecordcount": -1,
  "@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.totalrecordcountlimitexceeded": false,
  "@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.globalmetadataversion": "44580385",
  "value": [
    {
      "@odata.etag": "W/\"44092798\"",
      "msdyn_flow_approvalrequestidx_owninguserid": "74503F71-FE6B-E911-A81B-000D3A37F60D",
      "statuscode@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue": "Active",
      "statuscode": 1,
      "msdyn_flow_approvalrequest_approval": {
        "statecode@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue": "Active",
        "statecode": 0
      }
    },
    {
      "@odata.etag": "W/\"44092799\"",
      "msdyn_flow_approvalrequestidx_owninguserid": "74503F71-FE6B-E911-A81B-000D3A37F60E",
      "statuscode@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue": "Active",
      "statuscode": 1,
      "msdyn_flow_approvalrequest_approval": {
        "statecode@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue": "Active",
        "statecode": 0
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Classes:

```
public class msdyn_flow_approvalrequests
{  
    public string? statecode { get; set; }
    public msdyn_flow_approvalrequest_approval[]? entity { get; set; }
}

public class msdyn_flow_approvalrequest_approval
{
    public string? statecode { get; set; }
}
```

Using `JsonConvert`: no properties being mapped - all are null:

```
   JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<msdyn_flow_approvalrequests>(jsondata);
```

Comment: Paste that JSON into Visual Studio (using the "Edit > Paste Special > Paste JSON as classes") and you'll see what C# classes you need to deserialize this. You're leaving out the outest most properties for one, then your first level (in the `value` node) has a `statuscode` (*not* `statecode`) property), and the `msdyn_flow_approvalrequest_approval` is just a single object - not an array/list of objects ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using JsonConvert: no properties being mapped - all are null:

Based on your json file and the defination, it seems your class decoration is not correct. To be more specific your property case are not in expected format.

Because in asp.net core the web default naming policy is camel case. But your odata doesn't followed up with the default naming policy as a result you are getting null value

In order to map your odata json proterty according to your POCO class you should decorate with `[JsonProperty]`.

Therefore, your corresponding class should be followed by `[JsonPropertyName("YourClassProperty")]`.

**Base property:**

So your base class has five property which are context, totalrecordcount, totalrecordcountlimitexceeded, globalmetadataversion and value. Thus your class should be like below:

```
public class ODataClass
{
    [JsonPropertyName("@odata.context")]
    public string ODataContext { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.totalrecordcount")]
    public int TotalRecordCount { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.totalrecordcountlimitexceeded")]
    public bool TotalRecordCountLimitExceeded { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.globalmetadataversion")]
    public string GlobalMetadataVersion { get; set; }

    public List<ValueItem> value { get; set; }
}
```

Child Property:

Your child properties are etag, msdyn_flow_approvalrequestidx_owninguserid, FormattedValue, statuscode, msdyn_flow_approvalrequest_approval and FormattedValue, statecode so the class would be:

```
public class ValueItem
{
    [JsonPropertyName("@odata.etag")]
    public string Etag { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("msdyn_flow_approvalrequestidx_owninguserid")]
    public string OwningUserId { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("statuscode@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue")]
    public string StatusCodeFormattedValue { get; set; }

    public int statuscode { get; set; }

    public ApprovalRequestApproval msdyn_flow_approvalrequest_approval { get; set; }
}



public class ApprovalRequestApproval
{
    [JsonPropertyName("statecode@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue")]
    public string StateCodeFormattedValue { get; set; }

    public int statecode { get; set; }
}
```

Json Deserialization :

```
var data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ODataClass>(jsonData);
 
var firstItem = data.value[0];

 var serializedJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(data, new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true });
```

**Note:** I am testing if the data format are correct in `data.value[0];` out of 2 collection, you can skip that as well.

Output:

[image]

[image]

**Note:** If you need more details, [please refer to this official document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/customize-properties?pivots=dotnet-8-0)

Answer (score 1):

Your classes should be like this.

```
public class MsDynFlowApprovalrequests
{
    [JsonProperty("@odata.context")]
    public string ODataContext { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.totalrecordcount")]
    public int TotalRecordCount { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.totalrecordcountlimitexceeded")]
    public bool TotalRecordCountLimitExceeded { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.globalmetadataversion")]
    public string GlobalMetadataVersion { get; set; }

    public List<ApprovalRequest> Value { get; set; }
}

public class ApprovalRequest
{
    [JsonProperty("@odata.etag")]
    public string ODataEtag { get; set; }

    public string msdyn_flow_approvalrequestidx_owninguserid { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("statuscode@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue")]
    public string StatusCodeFormattedValue { get; set; }

    public int statuscode { get; set; }

    public Approval msdyn_flow_approvalrequest_approval { get; set; }
}

public class Approval
{
    [JsonProperty("statecode@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue")]
    public string StateCodeFormattedValue { get; set; }

    public int statecode { get; set; }
}
```

Then, deserialize the JSON data using the `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` method:

```
var approvalRequests = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MsDynFlowApprovalrequests>(jsondata);
```